# Add new version of an existing document in wrkfront through api

Tags: workfront-api

I am workg on a workfron project where I am able to create a new folder and a new document where that document has been created with version v.1 and placed into that folder. Now I want to create a new version of that existing document through api call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to figure it out from their documentation.

To upload a new version of document in Workfront trough API you need to first upload it with a call to attask/api/v13.0/upload (WF documentation is ok for this, and you got this working you said)

Then POST call to DOCV and pass updates: handle from upload call, documentID and fileName.

```
attask/api/v13.0/DOCV?updates={"handle":"DOCUMENT-HANDLE","documentID":"DOCUMENT-GUID","fileName":"FOO.png"}
```

I hope that helps. :P